# May I daven wearing headphones?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, kavana-concentration

There are many paths to concentration. I have known students who doodle because it helps them focus on a lecture more effectively. Others like to listen to [music](http://www.independent.co.uk/student/student-life/Studies/how-music-could-help-you-to-concentrate-while-studying-a6907341.html) while they study either to help them focus, or to drown out other noises. If my kavana is increased by the removal of distractions, may I put headphones on while I daven my shmoneh esrei? [[related](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23484/listening-to-music-during-learning), but about learning]

Would it make a difference if

a. I had ear plugs in

b. I wore headphones but nothing came through them

c. the noise I listened to was ambient/environmental (rain, waves, white noise) as opposed to instrumental music (and is that any better/worse than music with lyrics)?

I know that one should be able to hear himself davening but even with headphones on, one can [hear](http://www.thenakedscientists.com/forum/index.php?topic=14386.0) his own voice.

One answer I have heard repeatedly is that we should conduct ourselves in a way which would be appropriate were we talking to a head of state. If I wouldn't address the president wearing headphones, then I shouldn't when I daven. But I also wouldn't address the president with a shawl on my head, or wearing leather straps, or shuckling so that equivalence is not exact.

If the goal is to increase my kavana is there any limit to what I can and can't do (barring actions which explicitly violate other halachot) to increase my focus and concentration?

Comment: Why do you think this would be a problem?

Comment: The people I have spoken to have a knee jerk reaction of "this is wrong" but I can't get any solid basis for the problem. So I'm still looking.

Comment: You would address the president with whatever standards of protocol are required; in this case, the required protocol includes tallis and tefilin. Also, to appear before the president with a large "I support Trump" button might not be considered rude or vulgar, because you demonstrate acceptance of the president's authority; so too when you come before Hashem with these mitzvos in hand, you demonstrate your acceptance of His Authority.

Comment: Usually, the comparison is likened more to a king than the president. I think this an important difference. A king usually has the power of life and death in his hands. And, so, G-d is the King of Kings, and certainly has the power of life and death. The U.S. president does not have these powers, at least not directly.

Comment: One problem with blocking out sounds with a headphone is that you may miss required public responses such as "Amen", Kedusha, etc.

Comment: That's why in my question I specified "while I daven my shmoneh esrei."

Comment: Ah. I missed that. Offhand, I think the problem may be related to split kavana. If there is nothing coming through the headphones, I think it's fine, other, than, perhaps a "dress code" problem (on take with your notion that it would be improper to come to the president wearing headphones.) Otherwise, I don't think it's possible to completely ignore sound through your headphones and devote 100% attention to the tefillah. Most people think of other things while davening, anyway. Why add another deterrent?

Comment: Unless listening actually increases focus. http://www.chopra.com/articles/5-types-of-music-to-enhance-focus-and-productivity

Comment: A tricky factor, imo, would be the classic, "Would I wear (noise-cancelling, for example) headphones in front of the King?" I would assume not, but I do not have external halachic basis.

Comment: @DanF but there is a difference here. God is more then a king. It is different. Would god want a more focused prayer with headphones or a distracted prayer without? Obviously, everything has to be done in a very respectful manner. But I would posit that a difference can be made.