# Davening and Bluetooth

Tags: halacha, tefilla

Is it Halachically permissible to daven Shemonah Esrei while wearing a Bluetooth device on my ear? Or would that be forbidden due to a lack of respect to Hakodosh Boruch Hu?

Comment: Possible dupe. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/77668/759

Comment: would you walk into a room with dignitaries with a bluetooth?

Comment: @sam, I'm not sure, actually, nowadays. In a decade it'll probably be perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Is it different from glasses?